# With gitlab 8.12, the gitlab .submodules file doesn't seem to be used

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm now upgraded to gitlab 8.12, I've added two submodules, but I'm unable to get the contents of those submodules. The `.gitmodules` file doesn't seem to be used here.

Here's the command I've used to get those submodules:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

So, Is there anything I've to add additionally to get the submodule contents ?

Answer (score 0):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39766926/6309), when you add a submodule, you need to add the .gitmodules file *and* the folder representing the root directory of the nested repo referenced by that submodule.

It is the [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)). You need to make sure that gitlink exists if you want your submodule to be properly checked out.

```
git ls-tree HEAD mysubmodule 
160000 commit c0f065504bb0e8cfa2b107e975bb9dc5a34b0398  mysubmodule 
   ^
   |- do you see 160000?
```