# git submodule init does absolutely nothing

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a strange problem with "git submodule init"

When I added the submodules using "git submodule add url location" it cloned the repository just fine and everything was ok.

When I pushed all my changes back to the parent repository, added the .gitmodules files, etc and cloned the repository back, I tried to initialise all the submodules using "git submodule init"

And nothing happens :( Literally nothing, no output, no extra files, it does not even attempt to do anything actually.

So I am wondering, what did I do wrong?

.gitmodules:

```
bash$ cat .gitmodules
[submodule "projects/subprojectA"]
    path = projects/subprojectA
    url = ssh://user@bitbucket.company.com/test/projectA.git

[submodule "projects/subprojectB"]
    path = projects/subprojectB
    url = ssh://user@bitbucket.company.com/test/projectB.git
```

Answer (score 47):

ok, I have figured out what I did wrong.

When I added the git submodules, I did a git status and it told me three things had changed

```
.gitmodules
projects/subprojectA
projects/subprojectB
```

when I was pushing all my changes to the repository, I didnt want to commit the submodules, cause I thought it would add all the files I just cloned, so I just did a git add .gitmodules and committed and pushed that.

But this is wrong, you need to do a git commit and commit everything it tells you, then when you do this, git registers those paths and when you clone, it will work.

but if you do not commit those folders, it wont register them and wont clone them when you clone the parent repository.

so that was my mistake, I misunderstood that adding those directories would add all the submodules code to the parent repository, I tried to sidestep that and it stopped working.

so just add your submodules and commit the results, it will all work out just fine :D

Thanks for Protectators help, regardless!

Comment: Thanks!!! You saved my life!!! Sorry but I am so happy I need to thank you, I have been debugging for hours!

Comment: Totally agree! You have no idea how much this was driving me crazy lol

Comment: Thanks. I am using Submodules in GitLab and their documentation doesnt mention this at all

Comment: Thanks! Does anyone know why git subodule does it this way? Between `.gitmodules`, `.git/modules` and needing to commit them like this, the module registration seems very redundant.

Comment: So if this happens the file is missing which points to the commit id of the submodule. The easiest way to fix is to re-add the submodule.

Answer (score 20):

Following worked for me in case of the `googletest` submodule:

```
git submodule add --force https://github.com/google/googletest.git googletest
```

So, you need to manually add submodule (note the `--force` flag).

Comment: also, you need to remove the dest folder. At least that works for me.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `--recursive` option when cloning. This option initializes all listed submodules :

```
git clone --recursive
```

In another case, if you want to initialize submodules of an git you just cloned, you can use

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: git submodule update --init --recursive does nothing here, no cloning, nothing, I am going to try git clone --recursive now

Comment: git clone --recursive does not clone the submodules either, I am using git version 2.10.0

Comment: yup, the one from my comment, is the one I have when I clone the repository, thats why I am a bit puzzled....