# git submodule update is stuck on "Cloning into ..." on remote VPS - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-submodules, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to run `git submodule update` command on my ubuntu machine but it hangs on `Cloning into '/home/ubuntu/mazerat/mazerat/tasks/instabotpy'...`

I checked following solutions but doesn't work.

> [git submodule init does absolutely nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39765663/git-submodule-init-does-absolutely-nothing/39766926)
>
> [Git submodules update is stuck](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206867175-Git-submodules-update-is-stuck)

Same instance works properly on macOS Mojave (Version 10.14.3) and Windows 10.

Also machine SSH public key is set on github.

I tried to run command as root (after set the root ssh key) for premission check but didn't matter.

***.gitmodules***

```
[submodule "mazerat/tasks/instabotpy"]
    path = mazerat/tasks/instabotpy
    url = git@github.com:motameni/instabot.py.git
```

Comment: Have you tried running `ssh -T git@github.com` from the VPS as suggested by [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/)?

Comment: No, I haven't. I've tested it now and doesn't response...

Comment: Sounds like the machine on which this is failing is unable to reach `github.com`, probably due to some sort of network configuration issue.

Comment: @AliMotameni it definitely sounds like a network problem.  We don't know what you're doing or how things, so we can't tell you what is specifically wrong.  But it sounds like there is a firewall (either on the node or somewhere else) that is blocking outbound ssh (port 22).

Comment: I imported my repo to gitlab and then tested ssh -T git@gitlab.com and it works. but still `git submodule update` is stuck!

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I had turned off the firewall. I think this is not a firewall issue.

Comment: The `ssh -T git@github.com` problem is about github limitations according to U.S. sanctions against Iran.